# How to print PDF files in a sequence using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, pdf

I have a bunch of PDF files that I would like to print in sequence on a windows 7 computer using Powershell.

```
get-childItem "*.pdf" | sort lastWriteTime | foreach-object {start-process $._Name -verb 'print'}
```

The printed files are sometimes out of order like 1) A.pdf, 2) C.pdf, 3) B.pdf 4) D.pdf.

Different trials printed out a different sequence of files, thus, I fear the error is related to the printing queue or the start-process command. My guess is that each printing process is fired without waiting for the previous printing process to be completed.

Is there a way to consistently print out PDF files in a sequence that I specify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are starting the processes in order, but by default `Start-Process` does not wait until the command completes before it starts the next one.  Since the commands take different amounts of time to complete based on the .PDF file size they print in whatever order they finish in.  Try adding the `-wait` switch to your `Start-Process`, which will force it to wait until the command completes before starting the next one.

EDIT: Found an article elsewhere on Stack which addresses this.  Maybe it will help.  https://superuser.com/questions/1277881/batch-printing-pdfs

Additionally, there are a number of PDF solutions out there which are not Adobe, and some of them are much better for automation than the standard Reader.  Adobe has licensed .DLL files you can use, and the professional version of Acrobat has hooks into the back end .DLLs as well.

If you must use Acrobat Reader DC (closed system or some such) then I would try opening the file to print and getting a pointer to the process, then waiting some length of time, and forcing the process closed.  This will work well if your PDF sizes are known and you can estimate how long it takes to finish printing so you're not killing the process before it finishes.  Something like this:

```
ForEach ($PDF in (gci "*.pdf"))
{
    $proc = Start-Process $PDF.FullName -PassThru
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $NumberOfSeconds
    $proc | Stop-Process
}
```

EDIT #2: One possible (but untested) optimization is that you might be able use the ProcessorTime counters `$proc.PrivilegedProcessorTime` and `$proc.UserProcessorTime` to see when the process goes idle.  Of course, this assumes that the program goes completely idle after printing.  I would try something like this:

```
$LastPrivTime = 0
$LastUserTime = 0
ForEach ($PDF in (gci "*.pdf"))
{
    $proc = Start-Process $PDF.FullName -PassThru
    Do
    {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        $PrivTimeElapsed = $proc.PrivilegedProcessorTime - $LastPrivTime
        $UserTimeElapsed = $proc.UserProcessorTime - $LastUserTime
        $LastPrivTime = $proc.PrivilegedProcessorTime
        $LastUserTime = $proc.UserProcessorTime
    } 
    Until ($PrivTimeElapsed -eq 0 -and $UserTimeElapsed -eq 0)
    $proc | Stop-Process
}
```

If the program still ends too soon, you might need to increase the # of seconds to sleep inside the inner Do loop.

Comment: The wait switch stopped the printing process after printing the first file.
`get-childItem "*.pdf" | sort lastWriteTime | foreach-object {start-process $._Name -verb 'print' -wait}`

My theory is that Adobe Reader which is invoked by the start-process command is never closed after printing the first document

Comment: I have set my program to wait 6 seconds before triggering the next printing. Although sometimes a file get printed out of sequence,  it seems to be a sweet spot between time and accuracy.

Comment: If you want to try to optimize the time further, you _might_ be able to detect when the process is idle using `$proc.PrivilegedProcessorTime` or `$proc.UserProcessorTime`, which should stop incrementing when the process is done printing.  You could also maybe adjust the time based on the size of the .PDF file (Using $PDF.Length inside the ForEach) assuming that larger PDF files take longer to print. Of course, size doesn't always directly relate to printing time, so YMMV.  Glad I could help.